# Is it a good idea to upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 20.10

Will editing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and changing `LTS` to `normal` and then upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 break WSL2 or cause issues/incompatibility.

Is it overall a good idea to do so? Can't find any official documentation regarding upgrades from LTS to normal?

Answer (score 0):

WSL2 is using Hyper-V so the Linux will behave like in Virtual Machine.
I tried upgrading Ubuntu on WSL1 and WSL2 both with no issues.
As the question if it is good idea, it depends on what you need from 20.10.